# How can I transfer bitcoins from a MultiBit wallet to another computer?

Tags: multibit, wallet-import, multibit-hd

I had bitcoins on MultiBit 0.12 on my old computer. I have moved the old computer's hard drive to an external hard drive. How can I transfer my bitcoins from the old hard drive to my new computer's MultiBit 0.15?

Comment: It's hard to follow your question. What is "hard drive info"? What, exactly, is on the external hard drive? Do you have any `.wallet` files?

Comment: sorry about that I had multibit version 0.12 on my last computer. I had 2.499 btc that I did not transfer out .wallet files are there as well as program I just want to access bitcoins and transfer them from multibit 0.12 that is on external hard drive into my current mutibit version 0.15 on my current computer

Comment: @scotthall Hi Scott, I've edited your question to make it clearer. I hope that I understood correctly what you were trying to ask, please feel free to edit it further to correct it to your situation.

Comment: I need to send my Bitcoins to other wallet. I update to Multibit 0.5.19 but I need change the fee, otherwise It will not do the transactions. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

MultiBit developer here. The version numbers you're supplying are not related to MultiBit. We currently have version 0.2.0 for MultiBit HD and 0.5.19 for MultiBit Classic. There has never been a 0.12 or 0.15 version. Are you sure that you have the correct wallet application?

That aside, if you need to empty your wallet in MultiBit Classic, you simply need to use File | Open to locate your wallet file, and then use the Send tab to transfer those bitcoins to another address. That address is provided by whichever wallet you'd like to use instead.

**Do not delete your old private keys in case someone sends you bitcoin to an old address**

Here's a help article that gives more details: https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_sendingBitcoin.html